# How can I attach Google Drive files to non-GMail email?

Tags: google-drive

I want my associates who use non-GMail email to be able to attach files to their emails, which I share with them on Google Drive. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to attach a copy of the _actual file_, or just include _a link_ to the file on your Google Drive?

Comment: I need to attach the actual file. We are a medical group and I want to attach up-dates to treatment information which my associates keep in their files.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done by sending a link to the file, since once you download a copy, it stops updating.